# how can we implement password-recovery by email in yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

> I tried to do some changes in common/config/main-local.php

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
                'username' => 'example@examplemail.com',
                'password' => '***************',
                'port' => '2525',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to check email password recovery in my local server. I tried but it didnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of your transport settings are incorrect, so it cannot send an email. For local server you can just set `useFileTransport` to true like:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
    // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
    // for the mailer to send real emails.
    'useFileTransport' => true,
],
```

Then check your `<app>/runtime/mail/`folder, where `*.eml` mail will be generated. Therefore you can click on your password-recovery link and proceed futher.

*P.S. Yii2 advanced template includes email password-recovery feature from the box (if you are implementing it from scratch)*